# How to filter on CSV data using filter on multiple columns

Tags: awk

I have following data set in csv and would like to filter this on multiple columns using awk (My Version is GNU 3.1.7)

**How can i use awk to filter on multiple columns**

i used following command but didn't give required result.

```
awk -F, '{ if ($7="3YM62AE#UUS" && $5="01CS") print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$14}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Let me know if i am using correct awk command.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Haven't tested it but you need to change from `=` to `==`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  if($7=="\"3YM62AE#UUS\"" && $5=="\"01CS\""){
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$14
  }
}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```